# Eigenbasis for linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am working on a question to determine if a linear operator is Hermitian and/or unitary.

We are given a vector subspace $V=\operatorname{span}(e^{ikx})$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$
and a linear operator $L(f(x))=f'(x)$

Applying the operator to the basis vector(s) we get $ike^{ikx}$ which is understandable.

But then in the solutions of my question, it says that $ike^{ikx}$ constitutes an eigenbasis of our operator $L$, with eigenvalues $ik$ (imaginary eigenvalues dismissing the possibility of $L$ being a Hermitian operator).

I fail to see the apparently obvious conclusion that the eigenvalues are $ik$ with eigenbasis $ike^{ikx}$. How do we know this?

Comment: You wrote it yourself: apply the operator $L$ to the elements $v=e^{ikx}$ of the basis of the subspace $V$ to obtain $L\ v = ik\ v$.

Comment: Try to write $f$ as a linear combination of $e^{ikx}$ and write $f' = \lambda f$ and then solve it

Comment: Of course it was right in front of me. thanks.

Comment: Take $\tilde{L}=iL.$ The operator becomes hermitian.